# Proper database design for an equipment status system

Tags: database, database-design

What is the better way to design a database where you have a table that contains a bunch of part ID's and another table which changes the status of the group of parts:

```
Parts
id: int
type: int

Group
id: int
part_one_id: int
part_two_id: int
.
.
.

Reports
id: int
group_id: int
status_id: int
date: datetime
```

When making this database I have two ways of tracking status. Add a status_id column to the group table and whenever I create a report for that group I update that column to the new status.

OR

When I need to get the status of the group I query the reports to find the latest report.

Comment: Your Group table is not normalized

Answer (score 1):

No, that's a bad idea. PartStatus is one possibility (the Riehl heuristic argument). But the status is probably an association class. You are kind of approximating that in Reports right now so maybe you just rename that.

Comment: Wat. I'm asking which is the better method and your answer is "No". Should I be tracking the status of the group inside the group table with a field called status_id OR should I base the status on the most recent report.

Comment: I was saying the Report is the better approach, but that the name is not a great one, I would name it PartStatus, and then if you want to have a report, you could have one that has one or more PartStatuses inside.

Comment: So every time I need to know the current status of the group, computing the most recent PartStatus is not bad?

Comment: No. Go read about Association classes. The rule is simple: if you need to store additional properties about some event or role oriented relationships, you need an assocation class. So, for example, if you take out a subscription to a magazine, the magazine is an entity, you are one (Subscriber) and there is an association class called Subscription. Prices are another example. If it's ok to have no ability to see when prices changed or what they were at some other time, great, put them in the Product table, otherwise, you need an association class with begin and end dates.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if people on this site read the question properly. My association class is reports.

Comment: OMG, Dude, read what I said! I said your table is like an association class, but that's a poor name for it. Reports is a terrible name for an association class. But why don't you leave it so you can feel like you were right.